# How to compress Image using image_picker - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker, flutter-image

I'm building an image compressor. For that, I'm using the flutter image_picker package, it has a property called imageQuality which let you reduce the size of the image.

What I'm trying to achieve is that first upload the image through imagePicker and then compress it. So I can get both original and compressed sizes (before and after).

Currently what it does is compress the size while uploading/picking the image. That's what I do not want. How can I break into two steps (first upload and then compress the size using image quality parameter)

```
  void selectImage() async {
    final imagePicker = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 80); // upload and compress (I want to split this process)
    photoSize = await getFileSize(imagePicker!.path, 1);
    setState(() {
      _file = File(imagePicker.path);
    });
  }
```

Comment: you can use maxwidth and maxheight too, use aspectratio, and use imagequality in it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter & Firebase: Compression before upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515679/flutter-firebase-compression-before-upload-image)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question why don't you use [Image_compression_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/image_compression_flutter) to compress image after you have selected the image with `imageQuality: 100`
.

By using another compression function , you can compress the image and get the compressed image as output.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70375995/15215450) for the complete example code.

You can try compressing the image using the following function.

Please refer to the below plugins for compressing image

flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0

```
Future<File> compressImage(File file) async {
    final filePath = file.absolute.path;
    final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.png|.jp'));
    final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
    final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

    if (lastIndex == filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.png'))) {
      final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
          filePath, outPath,
          minWidth: 1000,
          minHeight: 1000,
          quality: 50,
          format: CompressFormat.png);
      return compressedImage;
    } else {
      final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        filePath,
        outPath,
        minWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 1000,
        quality: 50,
      );
      return compressedImage;
    }
  }
```

```
 File photoCompressedFile =
            await compressImage(File(pickedImage.path));
        print("Path of Compressed File: ${photoCompressedFile.path}");
```